# is it possible to include a dynamic blade view in another blade view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

i know traditionally we include files in blade view like @include('file.path.etc')
or @extends('file.path.etc') but here i am trying to include my dynamic view (which includes variables containing data from database) to be used as a section inside my static welcome page view(which is a default one which builds up when you create your project). when i tried to include it, it gave me errors because of the variables that could not be included inside the default welcome.blade.php
here is the error that i get [error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry3wP.png) a already tried it with including the file in and yielding the section in it.
 and here is the code that i tried to include

```
<section class="section swatch-red-white">
        <div class="container">
            @if($continents)
                <header class="section-header underline">
                    <h1 class="headline hyper hairline">Meet the team</h1>
                    <p class="">Your bones don&#x27;t break, mine do. That&#x27;s clear. Your cells react to bacteria and viruses differently than mine. You don&#x27;t get sick, I do. That&#x27;s also clear. But for some reason, you and I react the exact same way to water. We swallow it too fast, we choke.</p>
                </header>
                <div class="row">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled row box-list">
                        @foreach($continents as $continent)
                            <li class="col-md-4 os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".0s">
                                <div class="box-hex flat-shadow box-huge">
                                    <div class="box-dummy"></div>
                                    <figure class="box-inner">
                                        <img class="svg-inject" src="{{$continent->photo ? asset($continent->photo->file) : asset('images/404.png')}}" alt="a man with a mustache">
                                        <figcaption class="box-caption">
                                            <h4>Likes</h4>
                                            <p>Coffee and Beer</p>
                                        </figcaption>
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                                <h3 class="text-center">
                                    <a href="#">{{$continent->name}}</a>
                                </h3>
                                <ul class="list-inline text-center social-icons social-simple">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#" target="_self"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>
    </section>
```

here is the code of the controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $continents = Continent::all();
        return view('admin.continent.continent',compact('continents'));
}
```

and here is the part of the welcome.blade.php where i am trying to invoke the data form.

```
<div id="content" role="main">
    <section class="section swatch-red-white">
        <div class="background-media" style="background-image: url({{asset('images/design/section-bg/bg-2.jpg')}}); background-repeat: ; background-size: ; background-attachment: ; background-position: ; background-size: cover" data-start="background-position: 50% 0px" data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% -200px"></div>
        <div class="background-overlay" style="background-color:rgba(231,76,60,0.8)"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <header class="section-header underline">
                <h1 class="headline hyper hairline">Welcome to One58 Travel & Tour</h1>
                <p class="big">We make your dream vacations come true</p>
            </header>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section swatch-white-red has-top">
        <div class="decor-top">
            <svg class="decor" height="100%" preserveaspectratio="none" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M0 0 L100 100 L0 100" stroke-width="0"></path>
            </svg></div><div class="container">
            <header class="section-header underline">
                <h1 class="headline super hairline">Features</h1>
                <p class="">Angle is a uniquely designed wordpress theme. It&#x27;s super easy to modify and uses advanced CSS techniques built on the latest Bootstrap Framework.</p>
            </header>
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list-unstyled row box-list">
                    <li class="col-md-3 text-center os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".0s">
                        <div class="box-round">
                            <div class="box-dummy">
                            </div>
                            <a class="box-inner" href="#">
                                <img class="svg-inject" src="{{asset('images/design/custom-icons/custom-icon-composer.png')}}" alt="a clock" data-animation="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="text-center">
                            <a href="#">Retina ready</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p class="text-center">Angle is build to look sharp ,cool and awesome on all displays. Images will look sharp and clear.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-3 text-center os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".3s">
                        <div class="box-round">
                            <div class="box-dummy">
                            </div>
                            <a class="box-inner" href="#">
                                <img class="svg-inject" src="{{asset('images/design/custom-icons/custom-icon-bag.png')}}" alt="a clock" data-animation="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="text-center">
                            <a href="#">Free updates</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p class="text-center">No need to worry on keeping your theme updated. With Angle you get free updates for life.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-3 text-center os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".6s">
                        <div class="box-round">
                            <div class="box-dummy">
                            </div>
                            <a class="box-inner" href="#">
                                <img class="svg-inject" src="{{asset('images/design/custom-icons/custom-icon-iphone-white.png')}}" alt="a clock" data-animation="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="text-center">
                            <a href="#">Responsive Design</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p class="text-center">We have designed this site mobile first so it looks great on mobile devices of all sizes.</p>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-3 text-center os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".9s">
                        <div class="box-round">
                            <div class="box-dummy">
                            </div>
                            <a class="box-inner" href="#">
                                <img class="svg-inject" src="{{asset('images/design/custom-icons/custom-icon-clipboard.png')}}" alt="a clock" data-animation="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="text-center">
                            <a href="#">100% support</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p class="text-center">With Angle as with all our themes you will receive our 100% rock solid support.</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    {{--@include('admin.continent.continent')--}}
    {{--@section('continent')--}}
        {{--{{View::make('continents')->with('continents', $continents)}}--}}
        {{--@endsection--}}
    <section class="section swatch-white-red has-top">
        <div class="decor-top">
            <svg class="decor" height="100%" preserveaspectratio="none" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M0 0 L100 100 L0 100" stroke-width="0"></path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <header class="section-header underline">
                <h1 class="headline super hairline">Meet the team</h1>
            </header>
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="list-unstyled row box-list">
                    <li class="col-md-4 os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".0s">
                        <div class="box-round flat-shadow box-big">
                            <div class="box-dummy">
                            </div>
                            <figure class="box-inner">
                                <img class="svg-inject" src="{{asset('images/design/people/man-1-800x800.png')}}" alt="a clock">
                                <figcaption class="box-caption">
                                    <h4>Likes</h4>
                                    <p>Coffee and Beer</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="text-center">
                            <a href="#">John Langan</a>
                            <small class="block">Art Director</small>
                        </h3>
                        <p class="text-center">Your bones don’t break, mine do. That’s clear. Your cells react to bacteria and viruses differently than mine. You don’t get sick, I do. That’s also clear. But for some reason, you and I react the exact same way to water. We swallow it too fast, we choke.</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline text-center social-icons social-simple">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" target="_self">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" target="_self">
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-4 text-center os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".3s">
                        <div class="box-round flat-shadow box-big">
                            <div class="box-dummy"></div>
                            <figure class="box-inner">
                                <img class="svg-inject" src="{{asset('images/design/people/woman-1-800x800.png')}}" alt="a clock">
                                <figcaption class="box-caption">
                                    <h4>Says</h4>
                                    <p>I like ancient stuff</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="text-center">
                            <a href="#">Kate Ross</a>
                            <small class="block">Creative Director</small>
                        </h3>
                        <p class="text-center">Your bones don’t break, mine do. That’s clear. Your cells react to bacteria and viruses differently than mine. You don’t get sick, I do. That’s also clear. But for some reason, you and I react the exact same way to water. We swallow it too fast, we choke.</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline text-center social-icons social-simple">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" target="_self">
                                    <i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" target="_self">
                                    <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-4 text-center os-animation" data-os-animation="fadeInUp" data-os-animation-delay=".6s">
                        <div class="box-round flat-shadow box-big">
                            <div class="box-dummy"></div>
                            <figure class="box-inner">
                                <img class="svg-inject" src="{{asset('images/design/people/man-2-800x800.png')}}" alt="a clock">
                                <figcaption class="box-caption">
                                    <h4>Moto</h4>
                                    <p>Live and let die</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <h3 class="text-center">
                            <a href="#">Manos Jones</a>
                            <small class="block">IOS Developer</small>
                        </h3>
                        <p class="text-center">Your bones don’t break, mine do. That’s clear. Your cells react to bacteria and viruses differently than mine. You don’t get sick, I do. That’s also clear. But for some reason, you and I react the exact same way to water. We swallow it too fast, we choke.</p>
                        <ul class="list-inline text-center social-icons social-simple">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" target="_self">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" target="_self">
                                    <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" target="_self">
                                    <i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section swatch-red-white has-top">
        <div class="decor-top">
            <svg class="decor" height="100%" preserveaspectratio="none" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 100 100" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M0 100 L100 0 L100 100" stroke-width="0">
                </path>
            </svg>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="slider-flex3" class="flexslider text-left" data-flex-speed="7000" data-flex-animation="slide" data-flex-controls="hide" data-flex-directions="show" data-flex-controlsalign="center" data-flex-captionhorizontal="alternate" data-flex-captionvertical="bottom" data-flex-controlsposition="" data-flex-directions-type="">
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <li>
                            <figure>
                                <img style="height: 150px; width:150px " src="{{asset('images/design/vector/slide-1.png')}}" alt="some image">
                                <figcaption>
                                    <h3>Colorful and clean</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae, iure voluptatem dolore pariatur deleniti nihil cupiditate vel sunt consectetur.</p>
                                </figcaption>
                            </figure></li>
                        <li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="section swatch-red-white has-top">
```

And here is the Model of Continent

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Continent extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','photo_id',
    ];
    public function tour(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tour');
    }
    public function photo(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Photo');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `View::make('continents');` in your web.php file to render this blade? I'm pretty sure that whatever view you make you have to pass your variable in with it.

Comment: yeah i have tried it in welcome.blade.php but it didn't worked.

Comment: What I'm asking is how are you navigating to the page? Because you will have to pass the variable to the page when you navigate to it. Unless you declare it as global.

Comment: that is what i am trying to ask,  the real deal is how would you pass variables that are defined at one place to  work when the blade file is included in an other???

Comment: Where are you defining the variables? If you are defining them on the backend then you would send them with this `View::make('continents')->with('continents', $continents);`

Comment: You pass variables from the controller. Can you post the controller where you generate the $continents variable?

Comment: @zuif check the updated question

Comment: **Blade's @include directive allows you to include a Blade view from within another view. All variables that are available to the parent view will be made available to the included** [Including Sub-Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#including-sub-views)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share data with views in three ways:

### Pass data to a view

Pass an array of data to view:

```
return view('greetings', ['name' => 'Victoria']);
```

or, using the `with` method:

```
return view('greeting')->with('name', 'Victoria');
```

### Sharing Data With All Views

Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views that are rendered by your application. You may do so using the view facade's share method. Typically, you should place calls to share within a service provider's boot method. You are free to add them to the AppServiceProvider or generate a separate service provider to house them.

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::share('key', 'value');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

### View Composers

If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize that logic into a single location.

1. Register the view composers within a service provider
2. Define the composer class

You can also attach a view composer to multiple views at once by passing an array of views as the first argument to the composer method.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers for example

Answer (score 0):

Execute this line of code from wherever you are generating the list of continents.

```
View::make('continents')->with('continents', $continents);
```

Comment: still doesn't work, i have passed it like this  @include('admin.continent.continent')
    @section('continent')
        {{View::make('continents')->with('continents', $continents)}}
        @endsection

Comment: Sorry but I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. The traditional approach would be to let Vue.js handle an ajax request and render your html but since I don't know how you are rendering the page then I don't know when you are setting the $continents variable, where you are sending it from or anything like that. You may have to provide more information if you want a definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass continents as params to included view

```
@include('admin.continent.continent', ['continents'=>$continents])
```

Comment: It is possible that Continent::all() produces some value, that compact couldn't process, so view couldn't get value.

Comment: And also i don't understand why are you calling 'admin.continent.continent' view in controller instead of 'welcome'

Comment: no there're just name and photo_id which compact should be getting cause the same code is working on the other page. And i am using "admin.continent.continent" in controller because i wants to have same view at to different places. and i am trying to include that "admin.continent.continent" view in welcome.blade.php